# Add 1 day to bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have 2 bootstrap datepickers.when i choose date on first datepicker,(example 26/01/2021) then second datepicker must show that date but 1 day ahead and chosen date is disabled (min date).my code is work,but i dont know where can i apply that function i am asking for.

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" id="txtFromDate" />
<input class="form-control" id="txtToDate" />
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: 1,
    //startDate: new Date(),
    todayHighlight: false,
    //endDate: new Date()
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    $('#txtToDate').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
    $("#txtToDate").val($("#txtFromDate").val());
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

$("#txtToDate").datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    todayHighlight: true,
    //endDate: new Date()
}).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
});
```